# Unbeatable Nine Men's Morris AI?

Tags: computer-ai, nine-mens-morris

Supposedly Nine Men's Morris is a solved game that always ends in a draw if both players play perfectly. Has anybody successfully implemented an AI that achieves this perfect level of play? If so, how can I play against it?

[image]

Comment: If you cant get an answer here, try also at AI stack exchange https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Gábor E. Gévay et al. have made such an engine.

The program and instructions for downloading the databases necessary for perfect play can be found [here](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/%7Eggevay/mills/).